# How do I import a directory (and subdirectory) listing in Java?

Tags: java, path, directory

Here is the code I have thus far:

```
import java.io.*;

class JAVAFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return (name.endsWith(".java"));
    }
}

public class tester {
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
        FilenameFilter filter = new JAVAFilter();
        File directory = new File("C:\\1.3\\");
        String filename[] = directory.list(filter);
   }
}
```

At this point, it'll store a list of all the *.java files from the directory C:\1.3\ in the string array *filename*. However, i'd like to store a list of all the java files also in subdirectories (preferably with their path within C:\1.3\ specified also. How do I go about doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you will have to do this manually (recursively), i.e. you will have to call list(filter) for all sub-directories of C:\1.3\, and so on....

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you can't do it with the `list(FilenameFilter)` method. You'll have to list all files and directories, and then do the filtering yourself. Something like this:

```
public List<File> getFiles(File dir, FilenameFilter filter) {
    List<File> ret = new ArrayList<File>();
    for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            ret.addAll(getFiles(f, filter));
        } else if (filter.accept(dir, f.getName())) {
            ret.add(f);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you should look at [DirectoryWalker](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/DirectoryWalker.html) from Apache